# How can I make more partitions in Spark without causing a shuffle

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Basically my use case is such that in the firt stage, I can only have a few partitions, since each task runs a C program which takes as much as 10 GB of memory. However, I use a RangePartitioner later on. But with few partitions in the previous stage, the RangePartitioner throws out of memory errors while performing the suffle. This is a known fact that when you have too few partitions, Spark can throw out of memory errors during a shuffle.

Now, what I want is to simply divide the already existing partitions into more partitions. Basically, the opposite of what coalesces does in Spark. If I use a partitioner, such as the HashPartitioner, it would obviously cause a shuffle, which I want to avoid. So, how can I achieve this?

Comment: No you can not. That is how it is.

Comment: That is sad. Nobody could implement such a simple thing in Spark :(.

Comment: No. Nobody "wanted" to implement such a simple thing in Spark. :P

Answer (score 3):

Not at this time. You can track related JIRA ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5997